# Dimiss Touch Id action in Xcode 7 UI Automation

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-ui-automation

I am writing UI test case in Xcode 7 with new automation framework but I am not getting the method name to verify whether a touch prompt came or not and then dismiss a touch id prompt which is displayed in my app.

Answer (score 1):

I could not simulate finger touch but i was able to cancel the touch id prompt using addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription api available in the test framework

I used the below code to dismiss the dialog

```
  addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Touch ID") { (alert) -> Bool in
                alert.buttons["Cancel"].tap()
                return true
            }
           app.tap()
```

Comment: Seems that monitor doesn't work in Xcode 9 anymore. Completion block is not invoked

Answer (score 1):

I was able to implement a solution for our project using this Biometrics testing repo here:

https://github.com/KaneCheshire/BiometricAutomationDemo

After the event that kicks off the biometrics alert is completed, you will be able to handle that alert in a number of ways. Using the Obj-C files provided in this repo (and implementing a bridging header) you can provide an invalid or valid biometric for the alert.

Here is a cheat sheet for checking for the existence of an element and dismissing alerts: http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/

If you wish to tap "cancel" on the alert, you can do this a number of ways (as mentioned in the cheat sheet I posted) including using the Springboard API.

```
    func cancelBiometricAlert() {

    let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
    let biometricCancelButton = springboard.alerts.buttons["Cancel"].firstMatch
    if biometricCancelButton.exists {
        biometricCancelButton.tap()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss a Touch ID prompt by invalidating authentication LAContext. Dismissing TouchID prompt is introduced in iOS9:-

```
func invalidateAuthenticationAlert(authContextObjext: LAContext){

    print("Dismiss current prompt")
    authContextObjext.invalidate()
}
```

**Remember:-**

- The context is invalidated automatically when it is (auto)released. This method allows invalidating it manually while it is still in scope.
- Invalidation terminates any existing policy evaluation and the respective call will fail with LAErrorAppCancel. After the context has been invalidated, it can not be used for policy evaluation and an attempt to do so will fail with LAErrorInvalidContext.
- Invalidating a context that has been already invalidated has no effect.

Comment: Its pretty easy to dismiss the alert using code but i want to monitor system touch id alert appeared on the UI in the UI test

Comment: I was looking to do the same thing.  It seems that the TouchID Enrolled and Simulated Finger Touch functionality of the Simulator cannot be replicated via code.  Could you please post if you find an answer?  If not, you might want to consider submitting a feature request to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

In **Xcode 9** you can access the Springboard to dismiss the TouchID prompt:

```
func testExample() {
    let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()

    // this causes the TouchID prompt to be displayed
    app.buttons["Press Me!"].tap()

    if springboard.alerts.buttons["Cancel"].waitForExistence(timeout: 10) {
        springboard.alerts.buttons["Cancel"].tap()
    }

    // continue test
}
```